# Matter.JS causing words to fall endlessly

Tags: javascript, matter.js

I have a webpage I’m working on but I can’t seem to get the code correct. When the webpage loads the words fall correctly, but then start generating again in the top right outside the container and falling endlessly. Once this issue happens I just reload the page and it doesn’t happen again till I close the webpage out completely and launch it again. Can anyone identify how to resolve the issue?

```
      body: Matter.Bodies.rectangle(canvasSize.width / 2, 0, width, height, {
        render: {
          fillStyle: "transparent"
        }
      }),
      elem: elemRef,
      render() {
        const { x, y } = this.body.position;
        this.elem.style.top = `${y - 20}px`;
        this.elem.style.left = `${x - width / 2}px`;
        this.elem.style.transform = `rotate(${this.body.angle}rad)`;
      }
    };
  });

  const mouse = Matter.Mouse.create(document.body);
  const mouseConstraint = Matter.MouseConstraint.create(engine, {
    mouse,
    constraint: {
      stiffness: 0.2,
      render: {
        visible: false
      }
    }
  });
  mouse.element.removeEventListener("mousewheel", mouse.mousewheel);
  mouse.element.removeEventListener("DOMMouseScroll", mouse.mousewheel);

  World.add(engine.world, [
    floor,
    ...wordBodies.map((box) => box.body),
    wall1,
    wall2,
    top,
    mouseConstraint
  ]);
  render.mouse = mouse;
  Runner.run(engine);
  Render.run(render);

  (function rerender() {
    wordBodies.forEach((element) => {
      element.render();
    });
    Matter.Engine.update(engine);
    requestAnimationFrame(rerender);
  })();
};

window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", (event) => {
  splitWords();
  renderCanvas();
});
```

I’m trying to get the words to fall only in the container, eliminating the need to scroll off the page

Comment: I think some of the code got cut off here, like where `wordBodies` was defined. Could you clarify the complete script? Thanks!